# Save As HTML in Windows application?

Tags: html, windows, macos, text, editor

This should be such a no brainer, but I'm on a Mac and have yet to find a good workaround for Windows.

Here is what I do on my Mac that I need to recreate in a Windows environment OR with an online text editor:

1. Copy text from a PDF
2. Paste text in TextEdit
3. Do "Save As" and choose HTML

And that's it.

Notepad on Windows is all plain text so it loses formatting. And other text editors I've used can only save as .htm.

The final product needs to be a single HTML file with the original formatting of the PDF. Windows or through a web app both work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has to be exact, this app seems relevant:  http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/convert-pdf-files-to-html-format-in-windows-mac-and-linux/

Comment: This looks great. I should have added in the question though that it needs to be usable by extremely non-technical people, e.g. my mom.

Answer (score 0):

Use an actual word processor -- notepad is very much a plain text editor, which textEdit is not.

I'd recommend LibreOffice.

Comment: Even if I use a Word Processor like Word... still not Save As HTML option. Only .htm.

Comment: @TrevorMcKendrick There's no difference except filename between .htm and .html -- it's the same format.